# Adapting Retrofit responses using GSON

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I would like to agnostically retrieve the child element of a known JSON object with every successful response I receive from a particular API.

Each server response returns the following JSON format (condensed for simplicity):

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "error_title": "",
    "error_message": "",
    "data": {
        "messages": [
            { "message_id": "123",
              "content": "This is a message" },
            { "message_id": "124",
              "content": "This is another message" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Error responses contain the same, general format, with the "data" object being empty and the error-related JSON objects containing useful values. In the case of an error, I would like to extract the error-related JSON objects.

With the above response, I have a `MessageResponse` class that contains status, errorTitle, and errorMessage String properties as well as a `MessageData` object. The `MessageData` object then contains a list of messages - `List<Message> messages`. My GET method for getting messages in this case is as follows (condensed for simplicity):

```
@GET("/chat/conversation")
void getMessages(Callback<MessageResponse> callback);
```

This design requires three classes for *each* response type if I were to stick to the default POJO mapping that GSON's serializer provides out-of-box. My end goal is to cut down on the amount of classes necessary by reading only what I need from a successful server response and ignoring the rest. I would like all my success, callback data types on this API to be as close to the "data" content as possible.

In other words, I would like to agnostically return the child element of "data". In the case above, it is an array called "messages", but in some other response it could be a "user" object, for example. I know this can be done by registering separate `TypeAdapter`s for each response type, but I would like to achieve my end goal by using a single, *generic* solution.

**UPDATE: Implementation of David's suggestion from below**

```
public class BaseResponse<T> {
     @SerializedName("status") public String status;
     @SerializedName("error_title") public String errorMessageTitle;
     @SerializedName("error_message") public String errorMessage;
     @SerializedName("data") public T data;
}

public class MessagesResponse extends BaseResponseData<List<Message>> {
     @SerializedName("messages") List<Message> messages;
}

@GET("/chat/conversation")
void getMessages(Callback<BaseResponse<MessageResponse>> callback);
```

Unfortunately this is not getting serialized properly. If only I could somehow inform GSON of a variably-named JSON object child from the "data" parent and deserialize that child into a model class that is referred to by a generic data type. Essentially, `dataJsonObject.getChild()`.

Comment: So you have a fixed JSON structure, but `data` could be *anything*? Or just any of a number of predefined types? If the latter is true, I haved used a generic `BaseResponse<T>` where `data` is of type `T`. And then, for example, a `UserResponse extends BaseResponse<User>` that just needs to implement a constructor and inherits everything else from the `BaseResponse`.

Comment: @david.mihola Thanks for the great idea. I tried fitting my model setup to your proposed design, but I received a null list of posts back. See above for my modifications. Could you provide example code to illustrate your solution?

Comment: I just posted sample classes from our project!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a few hours of unsuccessfully feeding generic, base response classes to GSON, I ended up passing on that route and settling on a solution that I implemented a few days ago (minus the status check conditionals).

GSON provides the ability to add a `TypeAdapter` to all responses by defining deserialization logic in a generic `TypeAdapterFactory`. This entity is not as clean and ignorant as I was hoping for it to be, but it does the job in achieving a reduction in the number of necessary response model classes while also maintaining a single adapter.

```
private static class ResponseTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final String STATUS = "status";
    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String DATA = "data";

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        final TypeAdapter<T> delegateAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> jsonElementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegateAdapter.write(out, value);
            }

            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                // Ignore extraneous data and read in only the response data when the response is a success
                JsonElement jsonElement = jsonElementAdapter.read(in);
                if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                    if (jsonObject.has(STATUS)) {
                        if (jsonObject.get(STATUS).getAsString().equals(SUCCESS)) {
                            if (jsonObject.has(DATA) && jsonObject.get(DATA).isJsonObject()) {
                                jsonElement = jsonObject.get(DATA);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return delegateAdapter.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
            }
        }.nullSafe();
    }
}
```

In a nutshell, I'm telling GSON to grab the "data" JSON object if the response was successful. Otherwise, return the entire response body so that my custom, Retrofit error handler can make use of the "error_title" and "error_message" fields returned from the server.

A huge shoutout to @david.mihola for the great suggestions and eventually directing my attention back to the `TypeAdapterFactory` solution.

Comment: In retrofit 1.9 this worked like a charm, but in retrofit 2.0 I am not able to implement this. Any ideas on how to make this work for retrofit 2.0 ?
Thanks\

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to your question but maybe an alternate solution to the same problem of having multiple redundant classes for a lot of similar responses:

This is our `AbstractResponse`:

```
public abstract class AbstractResponse<T> {

    @SerializedName("success")
    private boolean success;

    // used for error handling
    @SerializedName("error")
    private String errorMessage;

    @SerializedName("code")
    private Integer errorCode;

    // used for normal operation
    @SerializedName("data")
    protected T data;

    @SerializedName("details")
    private DetailsError details;

    @SerializedName("points")
    private Integer points;

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public DetailsError getDetailsError() {
        return details;
    }

    public Integer getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public Integer getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public AbstractResponse(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AbstractResponse{" +
                "success=" + success +
                ", errorMessage='" + errorMessage + '\'' +
                ", errorCode=" + errorCode +
                ", data=" + data +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And then there are classes like this one:

```
public class VotingImageListResponse extends AbstractResponse<List<VotingImage>> {

    public VotingImageListResponse(List<VotingImage> data) {
        super(data);
    }

}
```

which are used by Retrofit like this:

```
@GET("/api/VotingImage")
public void getVotingImages(@Query("voting_id") Integer id, @Query("app_user_id") Integer userId, @Query("session") String sessionId, Callback<VotingImageListResponse> callback);
```

And that's all.

**EDIT**:

Just to make it more clear, this is `VotingImage`:

```
public class VotingImage implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("voting_image_id")
    private final Integer votingImageId;

    @SerializedName("voting_id")
    private final Integer votingId;

    @SerializedName("image_id")
    private final Integer imageId;

    @SerializedName("url")
    private final Uri uri;

    @SerializedName("url_small")
    private final Uri uriSmall;

    // ...
}
```

Some more examples of concrete response classes:

```
public class ChoiceResponse extends AbstractResponse<Choice> {
    public ChoiceResponse(Choice data) {
        super(data);
    }
}
```

Where `Choice` is defined like this:

```
public class Choice {

    @SerializedName("question_list")
    private final PVector<Question> questions;

    @SerializedName("is_evaluation")
    private final Boolean isEvaluation;

   // ...
}
```

Or:

```
public class RegisterResponse extends AbstractResponse<RegisterResponseData>{
    public RegisterResponse(RegisterResponseData data) {
        super(data);
    }
}
```

with:

```
public class RegisterResponseData {

    @SerializedName("mail")
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("app_user_id")
    private Integer appUserId;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("session")
    private String sessionId;

    // ...
}
```

As you can see, even though the JSON attribute is always called "data" the type/content of that field can vary widely for each response. The only importat thing is that Retrofit knows (so that it can tell Gson) the type of your expected response. The generic class structure above is just a - I think - concise way of telling Retrofit/Gson what to parse the JSON to. The above example method could also be written directly like this:

```
@GET("/api/VotingImage")
public void getVotingImages(@Query("voting_id") Integer id, @Query("app_user_id") Integer userId, @Query("session") String sessionId, Callback<AbstractResponse<List<VotingImage> callback);
```

**One more thing**: This is not tested and I am not really able to test it now, but how about this:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractCallback<T> implements Callback<AbstractResponse<T>> {

    @Callback
    public void onSuccess(AbstractResponse<T> response) {
        // if (response was successful) {
            T data = response.getData();
            onRealSuccess(data);
        // }
    }

    public abstract void onRealSuccess(T data);
}
```

In that way you could also factor out the "unpacking" of the actual response data from the whole generic response.

Comment: I think this is close to what I'm looking for, but unfortunately the API returns a nested, variably-named JSON object _within_ "data", and I do not think I can fit that response to your solution. The "data" key is always constant, but the "data"'s child element is always variable (e.g. "messages" in the case above or "user", "speakers", whatever it may be). I can't seem to find a way to extract that variable without explicitly naming its key in an @SerializedName(key) annotation.

Comment: One question: Is there a direct correspondence between server URL/Retrofit method and the type of the response, i. e. for each single request do you know in advance the names and types used in the JSON?

Comment: There is no relationship between the HTTP URL and the data's child's type. The only way I know the type is by looking up the API documentation to check the key. I'm trying to think of a way to pass in a String representing the data's child's key to the GSON deserializer based on the given ```Callback<T>``` type.

Comment: I didn't necessarily mean an "obvious" or "self-evident" relationship i. e. that the URL "/myapi/<x>/" would always return an "X" in the JSON. But: When you call the API, do you know what to expect?

Comment: Yes, I do know what to expect from any API response. It's kind of implied by the ```Callback``` type.

Comment: Then I think there always should be a way to tell Gson what to do. However, Gson will always try to parse the whole JSON, so in `Callback<T>` the T must "fit" to the whole response, not just the "data". This in turn means, I think, that your `BaseResponseBody` should be generic, too... And it seems that you can't have a generic `BaseResponseData` - your should have a `MessageResponseData` and a `ModUserResponseData` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77452/discussion-between-david-mihola-and-ryan).