# Using GSON to serialize only nested JSON

Tags: java, json, api, gson, retrofit

I have an API that returns some arguably useful metadata along with requested data itself. It looks something like this:

```
{
"success": true,
"messages": [],
/* other metadata */
"result":  { /* fields with useful data */ }
}
```

So, basically I want to serialize only stuff that is nested inside of "result" field, preferably still being able to work with meta (checking "success" on true/false and reading messages might be useful).

I thought I could use JSONObject to separate "result" and other meta, but this pipeline feels like a bit of overhead. Is there a way to do it purely with GSON?

The other problem is that I use Retrofit, which has a very neat workflow with pure GSON. If the above is the only adequate way of dealing with such API, how should I approach integrating it into Retrofit workflow?

Comment: I had a similar need for this in the past. Checkout the [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114793/adapting-retrofit-responses-using-gson/30157359#30157359).

Answer (score 0):

to your retrofit builder add:

```
.addConverterFactory(new GsonConverterFactory(new GsonBuilder()
                    .registerTypeAdapter(Result.class, new JsonDeserializer<Result>() {
                        @Override
                        public Result deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                            if(!(((JsonObject) json).getAsJsonPrimitive("success")).getAsBoolean()) {
                                return null;
                            }
                            JsonObject result = ((JsonObject) json).getAsJsonObject("result");
                            return new Gson().fromJson(result, Result.class);
                        }
                    }).create()))
```

there are npe and other checks to do of course :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a POJO with @Expose annotation and use serialization = true/false. If you want to serialize only success, then your POJO would look something like this.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class POJO {
    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose(serialize = true, deserialize = false)
    private Boolean success;
    ///Your getter / setter methods
}
```

I have used this above with Retrofit and it works fine.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

Also you need to mention this while creating your Retrofit Service

```
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(YOUR_BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gsonBuilder.create()))
            .build();
```